# Unity launcher appear on gnome session, how to fix it?

Tags: unity, 13.10, gnome

Yesterday my gnome's completely broken, cause there are unity launcher on gnome session. I have no idea why this happen, see the picture:

[image: Unity stays on gnome]

And i'am not able to access gnome panel

[image: "ubuntu desktop" text on gnome panel]

Reinstalling no give me result

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-session-fallback
```

Note: before it, I was resetting gnome and this happen

Comment: Why don't you try with this command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3`?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Gnome Classic and Gnome Classic (no effects) is that the former runs Compiz. It seems Compiz has a Unity plugin, which if enabled, will bring forth that panel and menubar that is annoying you. See this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1883532) I found on the Ubuntu forums. The poster there used CCSM to disable the plugin. I don't know if that's the best way (CCSM doesn't have a great reputation, to say the least). You can search this site for alternatives to using CCSM.